# Vue.js not working, Error for "Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version."

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, vue.js

I am using laravel 5.4 for back end and using Vue.js for front end. I going to use Vue to passing the value to Controller and store the data. But when i checking the console, the response is showing the error

> Automatically populating `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` is deprecated and will
>   be removed in a future version.

The server i using is WAMPServer 3.0.6.
I found the solution is changing the php.ini, `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA=-1`, but still having the error.

So is there another solution for that?

This is my Vue code

```
<script>
export default {
    mounted(){

    },

    data() {
        return {
            content :'',
            not_working: true
        }
    },

    methods:{
        create_post() {
            this.$http.post('/create/post', { content:this.content })
                .then((resp)=> {
                    this.content = ''
                    noty({
                        type: 'success',
                        layout: 'bottomRight',
                        text: 'Your post has been posted.'
                    });
                    console.log(resp)

            })
        }
    },

    watch :{
        content(){
            if(this.content.length > 0)
                this.not_working = false
            else
                this.not_working= true
        }
    }
}
```

My Controller

```
public function store(Request $request){

    return Post::create([
        'body' => $request->content,
        'user_id' => Auth::id()

    ]);

}
```

UPDATED:
After i research from internet, seem like the problems was solved, but new problems happened, which is

```
TokenMismatchException
```

I included the `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

but still having this error, what should i do now?

Comment: First of all - are you using Axios or still vue-resource?

Comment: i still using vue-resource...

Comment: repalce it with axios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since i am lazy to find a way to adding token into vue resource function. Then i just change it to axios because it can avoid this error. So i just change

```
 this.$http.post('/create/post', { content:this.content })
```

to

```
 axios.post('/create/post', { content:this.content })
```

then it can solve the csrf-token problems. And i think this only work for laravel 5.4 because it is predefined.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is attaching proper header in your request,
here is the proper post request with proper header, I have tested myself and it is working.

```
var config = {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    responseType: 'blob'
 };

axios.post('/user', {}, config)
.then((response)=>{
    console.log(response)
}).catch((error)=>{
    console.log(error.response.data)
});
```

I hope the server will treat you well and not return the warning regarding **HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA**.

Answer (score 0):

```
methods: {

    onSubmit(){

        var formData = this.toFormData(this.$data); 

        axios.post('/projects', formData)
        .then(response => alert("success"))
        .catch(error => alert("inv") );
    },

    toFormData: function(obj){
        var form_data = new FormData();
        for(var key in obj ){
            form_data.append(key, obj[key]);
        }
        return form_data;
    }

}
```

//im using laravel 5.4 vue js 2,  no need for attaching proper header. just add the **toFormData**.